# Add contain to contained models in a Cakephp 3 query

Tags: sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have three models: `"Company"`, `"Boss_data"` ad `"Users"`. The `"Company"` table has several `user_ids`, one of which is refered to the boss (`boss_id`). The `"Boss_data"` is linked to the `"Users"` table by the `user_id`. What I'd like to do is build a query in which, when I get the company, I also get its "boss_data". Right now I have this query

```
$query = $this->Companies->find('all')->contain(['Users','Users_supervisor', 'Users_boss']);
```

which provides me with a structure like

```
Company
[
   {company attributes}
   user[],
   user_supervisor[],
   user_boss[]
]
```

While what I'd like is

```
Company
[
   {company attributes}
   user[],
   user_supervisor[],
   user_boss
   [
       boss_data[]
   ]
]
```

I have tried doing a left join or adding another contain clause to the query, but it seeems like that is not the correct way to do it, as I have not achieved what I wanted, so I'd like to know how I can get that data using the `Users` table as a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set all the links in the models correctly, the following query should give you your desired result:

```
$query = $this->Companies->find('all')->contain(['Users','Users_supervisor', 'Users_boss' => ['boss_data']]);
```

But you then implemented the users "Supervirsor" and "Boss" twice (as Supervirsor & Boss and in the users array). I would think about it again.